# I can't find the utility of the second const in this part of c++ code, can someone explain please?

Tags: c++, constants

const T & top() const { return m_Data.back(); }

Comment: Are you sure this is C and not C++? Someone retagged your post(rolled-back), but we need to know the language you're speaking about.

Comment: You're right this is C++, I missed the right tag

Comment: The assumption that every piece of code has utility is not quite valid. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that `this` pointer in member function is `const`. In other words that the call doesn't modify the object. (and whatever reference/pointer it returns will also be `const`).

Comment: My bad, first time on this awesome website, hit the wrong tag

Comment: I don't think it's a huge problem. Giving the right tags helps, though :)

Answer (score 3):

This syntax if for methods, inside classes. Methods marked as `const` (the second `const` in your code) can not modify the attributes of the object, only read. Const methods are the only callable methods if you instantiate your object as `const`. For intance:

```
class A {
public:
  void put(int v) {
    var = v;
  }

  int read() const {
    return var;
  }

private:
  int var;
}

int main() {
  A obj;
  obj.put(3);

  const A obj2 = obj;
  obj2.read(); // OK, returns 3;
  obj2.put(4); // Compile time error!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Michael's answer covers just about everything, but there are some other aspects:

- You're only allowed to call const methods inside a const method.
- You **can** change members if you declare them as mutable.
- You won't be able to change any other members of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Only member functions can be **const** qualified, non-member functions can not. The same is true for **C++** too. **C** has no concept of member functions and hence they can not.